# TypeError: string indices must be integers when using string split to pass paramerters to a json api

Tags: python, json

**This the main drive Im using to call the call the functions from the mentioned call.**

```
from primeReportController import PrimeReportController

input_str = input()

a = input_str.split(",",1)

report_date,report_name = a[0],a[1]

prime = PrimeReportController()
prime.generatePrimeReport(report_date,report_name)
```

**This is the call function definition writhing the class** 
[image]

Also please note the function adds the json data to a sql database. The data is already formatted to fit the table schema.

Comment: Hey! can you add the full stack trace? Or alternatively tell us where the error is occuring

Comment: {'message': 'The request is invalid.'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\smithde\Desktop\PrimeBOJReport\source code\generatePrimeReportMain.py", line 10, in <module>
    prime.generatePrimeReport(report_date,report_name)
  File "C:\Users\smithde\Desktop\PrimeBOJReport\source code\primeReportController.py", line 31, in generatePrimeReport
    values.append((report_name,report_date,x['cell'],x['cellValue']))
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: What does `response` look like?

Answer (score 0):

Since the output of `response.json()` is `{'message': 'The request is invalid.'}`, it tells you that your request is invalid to the server, and that the returning value would not have the data structure you expected. So when you iterate over the response dict with:

```
for x in server_response:
```

What it really does is to iterate over the keys of the dict `{'message': 'The request is invalid.'}`, `x` becomes `'message'` in the first iteration, so when you try to get the value of `x['cell']`, it consequently complains about your trying to access a string with a non-integer index.

You simply have to fix the request you send to the server first.